# Problems with localStorage with different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm getting a really hard time with this:

**HTML**

```
<body onload="load();">
...
<input id="group1first" class="group1first" type="radio" name="group1" value="Group-1 - First"><label for="group1first">Group-1 - First</label>
<input id="group1second" class="group1second" type="radio" name="group1" value="Group-1 - Second"><label for="group1second">Group-1 - Second</label><br>
<button type="button" onclick="applychanges()">Apply New Options</button>
```

I simply want to save the checked radio button by the user after he revisit the page with applied effect for this button, of course.

**JavaScript**

```
function load() {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if(document.getElementById('group1first').checked){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"; //just for test
            localStorage.setItem('group1', 'true');
        }
        else if(document.getElementById('group1second').checked){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";  //just for test
            localStorage.setItem('group1', 'false');
        }
        if(localStorage.getItem('group1') == 'true'){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"; //just for test
            document.getElementById('group1first').checked = true;
        }
        else {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green"; //just for test
            document.getElementById('group1second').checked = true;
        }
    } else {
        alert('Sorry! No Web Storage support.');
    }
}
function applychanges(){
window.location.reload(false); 
}
```

This is not working with chrome, partly with IE (the 'apply new options' buttons does not work, but if I select and hit <kbd>F5</kbd> it takes effect), in Firefox it works the best out of them all, but yet not as planned(on the first load the `group1second` is checked by default, I don't understand, why?

Comment: First issue: Your `id` and `classes` share the same name. Change that.

Comment: Why? It can't get conflict with each other if used properly. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's not good practice. Especially when you get into larger web apps and start working in teams of developers. It's better to just develop better habits to make life easier in the future.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I won't use it like this then. But unfortunately, it doesn't really solve the problem :/ I just don't know what may be wrong here. Google doesn't help to answer the question at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate the reading and the writing from/to local storage. The reading should happen on page load, the writing when you submit the changes.

So here is how it could look:

```
function load() {
    if (typeof Storage !== "undefined") {
        if(localStorage.getItem('group1') == 'true'){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"; //just for test
            document.getElementById('group1first').checked = true;
        }
        else {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green"; //just for test
            document.getElementById('group1second').checked = true;
        }
    } else {
        alert('Sorry! No Web Storage support.');
    }
}

function applychanges(){
    if (typeof Storage !== "undefined") {
        if(document.getElementById('group1first').checked){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"; //just for test
            localStorage.setItem('group1', 'true');
        }
        else if(document.getElementById('group1second').checked){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";  //just for test
            localStorage.setItem('group1', 'false');
        }
        window.location.reload(false); 
    } else {
        alert('Sorry! No Web Storage support.');
    }
}
```

The reason the second option is selected upon the first page load, is that `localStorage` has no `group1first` data yet, and so the first `if` condition in the `load` function is false. The `else` block selects the second option.

Comment: Thanks a million! ...I didn't even think about :( In firefox and chrome it works just perfect! With IE it was a little bit a mess, but I got the answer from the google(in case some one wiill need it): it may be because the local file(file://), otherwise it should work perfectly as well!  Trincot! Thanks one more time!